# OData WebAPI, in-memory queryable and case-sensitivity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, case-sensitive, asp.net-web-api-odata, asqueryable

I have a problem with OData WebAPI and querying a `EnumerableQuery` (a list on which I called `.AsQueryable()`. I have a entity set, a controller with a Get method which returns the `IQueryable`. When I query that entity set and use this $filter

```
$filter=SomeStringProp eq 'SomeValue'
```

I get only entities whose `SomeStringProp` equals `'SomeValue'` by letters and casing. I would like to somehow force OData to use a case-insensitive comparer for all strings - even with function calls like this

```
$filter=contains(SomeStringProp, 'apple')
```

I would need OData to return entities whose SomeStringProp is equal to `'APPLE'`, `'PineApple'` and `'AppleSauce'`

Some additional information:

- A database has nothing to do with this; as stated, the collection is in-memory
- Using tolower() in OData queries is just a workaround, so it's not a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not supported by Odata.

- The recommended way for case case-insensitivity is using [tolower (or toupper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495905/odata-query-filter-conditions-and-case-sensitivity).
- The contains keyword is already part of [odata v4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398117) and implemented in Web API.

Combine them both and your are done :)

Edit: Works just fine with the [sample WS](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/%28S%282jg0jzkrehhsuwbxo1slfevk%29%29/OData.svc/Products?$filter=contains%28tolower%28Name%29,%20tolower%28%27juice%27%29%29).