# OData casesensitive issue

Tags: c#, odata

Facing one issue while doing lambda query using OData.
For example below are the query which I am  doing:

Value that is stored in Database is Hubbardston

Scenario 1:

```
http://localhost:32339/Enquiry?$filter=relatedParty/any(r: r/religion eq 'Hubbardston')
```

Result: working fine

Scenario 2:

```
http://localhost:32339/Enquiry?$filter=relatedParty/any(r: r/religion eq 'hubbardston')
```

Result: Not working

So basically it is behaving like case sensitive, how can we make it case insensitive?

Comment: When you say `Not working`, does it mean you are not getting any result?

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495905/odata-query-filter-conditions-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is returning with blank object in scenario 2

Comment: @Oleg If it is not lambda query then we can apply tolower but here we can not apply, So I need resolution in case of lambda query

Comment: Can you try apply tolower('Value')

Comment: @Oleg No tolower is not working in my case.

Comment: What is the version of odata?

Comment: @Oleg it is 7.2.1.30805

Comment: it's yours server side and can you get the details?